# Why wont this post?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I'm playing around with mongodb + Express and rewriting an old comments app in the latest version of Express.

I've had to change a few things because of the changes in the latest Express. But I'm having some issues.

Basically, it won't post to `/create` when I submit my form. This is probably a simple fix but any help would be appreciated :)

**app.js**

```
require('./models/comments'); // require the model before the 'index.js' file is called

var express = require('express'); var path = require('path'); var favicon = require('static-favicon'); var logger = require('morgan'); var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index'); var create = require('./routes/create');

var app = express();

// Database stuff var mongoose = require('mongoose'); mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/comments-app');

// view engine setup app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon()); app.use(logger('dev')); app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()); app.use(cookieParser()); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes); app.use('/create', create);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err); });

/// error handlers

// development error handler // will print stacktrace if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    }); }

// production error handler // no stacktraces leaked to user app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    }); });


module.exports = app;
```

**Comments.js (model)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    content: String,
    created: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  div.addCommentForm
          form( method="post", action="/create")
          input(type='text', class='nameTxt', name='username')
  div
          span.label Comment :
          textarea(name='comment')
  div#addCommentSubmit
          input(type='submit', value='Save')
br
br
#comments
  - each comment in comments
    div.comment
      div.name comment.username
      div.created_at= comment.created
      br
      div.content= comment.content
      hr
```

**create.js (route)**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', Comment);


router.route('/create')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        var Comment = new Comment()
        username : req.body.username;
        content : req.body.comment;
        created : Date.now();

        Comment.save(function(err) { 
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.send('Comment added');
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jade indenting for the `form` tag is off. Make sure the `input` tags you want inside the `form` tag in the HTML are indented further than the `form` tag in your jade so they end up as children of the `form` tag in the HTML.

**Oops**:

this jade

```
form
input
```

yields this HTML

```
<form></form><input>
```

**Fixed**

```
form
  input
```

yields

```
<form><input></form>
```

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something simple :)

Now however i'm getting a error when I press submit:

Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
    at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle]

Comment: Your routes expect /create/create. You have '/create' in 2 .js files. Delete one of them.